# grouping all the declarations within the same media query

Tags: html, css

I made a separate media query for each style declaration. If the media query is the same, I assume you can group all the declarations within the same media query.
How do I do that?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
.component-text-block.small-image .no-wrap-text-right {
    width: 390px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
.component-text-block.small-image .image.left img {
    width: 168px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
.component-text-block-fullwidth.small-image .content-item img {
    width: 250px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **CSS Syntax** is:

```
@media not|only mediatype and (media feature) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

So, You can include all your **CSS Codes** like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
.component-text-block.small-image .no-wrap-text-right {
    width: 390px;
   }
.component-text-block.small-image .image.left img {
    width: 168px;
   }
.component-text-block-fullwidth.small-image .content-item img {
    width: 250px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Voting up